# Graylog2 'cluster' over VPN

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, graylog2

We have 2 locations connected by VPN.
Currently we have 2 independent graylog servers.

We want to create some kind co cluster, so we can reach logs on both sides even if VPN is down.
Is is something like this:
[image]

We already tried to create Elasticsearch cluster, but this is not the way.
If VPN is down whole cluster is down and logs not working on either side.

I found this article: https://www.elastic.co/blog/scaling_elasticsearch_across_data_centers_with_kafka

with such topology: [image]
but I have no idea how to configure Apache Kafka so it will be broker for graylog and input for syslog server.

Any help/another idea / link will be much appreciated.